# Creating conda environment package with adding its certificate

Tags: python, conda

I don't have https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-aarch64 as trusted resource. So when I try to create a conda-environment I am getting

```
$ conda create --name bot-maker python=3.8
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-aarch64/current_repodata.json>
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.

If your current network has https://www.anaconda.com blocked, please file
a support request with your network engineering team.

'https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-aarch64'
```

Now, it's similar issue with `wget` as well but there we can use `--no-check-certificate` and it's all goo.

Is there anything I can do here. Like download https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-aarch64/current_repodata.json file locally and share it's path to conda or some similar option using which I can skip `certificate verification`

Comment: Have you tried adding `-k`?

Comment: @FlyingTeller you're awesome!! `-k` is the exact thing I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Adding it as an answer then which you can accept to show that your problem ahs been resolved. Glad it helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the `-k` flag, from [the docs](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/create.html):

> -k, --insecure
> Allow conda to perform "insecure" SSL connections and transfers. Equivalent to setting 'ssl_verify' to 'false'.

Alternatively, you can set it permanently in the conda settings using:

```
conda config --set ssl_verify false
```